# Reuse ALB when moving from private to public

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-eks, aws-application-load-balancer

Currently, I am using `AWS Direct Connect`.

So, both `ALB` and `Cluster` of `EKS` are in private network.

Now, I want to allow access from outside.

So I change the ALB's subnet to `public`.

However, it still has no global IP adress.

And `Scheme` keeps `Internal`

In this case , I need to make the new `ALB` or is it possible to change `Internal` to `Internet-facing` for re-use `ALB`

And, the setting like this below is possible?

`EKS`(in private) - `ALB`(in public)

I wonder, if it works, what the purpose of setting such as put `EKS` in public?

Always put `EKS` in private is best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically need to create 2 load balancers: 1 internal facing, 1 external facing. The external load balancer accepts internet traffic whereas the internal load balancer accepts internal traffic, i.e. traffic originating from the VPC or networks connected to the VPC. If your service only needs to be accessed by other services within the cluster, you only need to create a service of type ClusterIP. You should be able to register your service with both load balancers by creating 2 ingress definitions. Each ingress definition will have its own ingressGroup, see https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.5/guide/ingress/annotations/#ingressgroup for additional information. You could also do this, using the [targetGroupBinding CRD](https://kubernetes-sigs.github.io/aws-load-balancer-controller/v2.5/guide/targetgroupbinding/targetgroupbinding/) but I would try ingress first.

You can't assign a static IP address to an ALB. If you want to use a static IP with an ALB you need to follow this pattern, https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/alb-static-ip.

Comment: Ah I see. I understood I should not re-use the old one ,but make two `ALB`. and also I don't need to use static IP. DNS is fine for my purpose.